# libusb not found mac os x 10.6.8

Tags: macos, compiler-construction, compilation

Can anybody tell me how to make my compiler find the libs that it is looking for.  As far as I can tell the libs are where it is supposed to be looking.  Perhaps there is a mac pro out there that will know how to get around this.

Below is the error that is causing the configuration fail

checking for usb_init... configure: error: libusb not found, use ./configure LIBUSB_LIBS=...

Below is what it dumped into the config.log file

[Pastebin to config.log file](http://pastebin.com/ns5HgVcB)

Comment: It looks like you're trying to build a fat binary for ppc and x86 - you should probably just be building for x86.

Comment: You'll need to pass the appropriate flags to your configure script

Comment: I tried passing the location to the libraries like it asks with the ... replaced with the location of the libraries.  Out side of that I dont know how to pass what is required to make it work.

Comment: In your Pastebin dump, I see `LIBUSB_LIBS` is defined twice (on line 7).  Was that intentional?  If you take out the latter definition, does that fix your problem?

Comment: That was because I passed it in on the command line because I was unsure that the script was properly detecting the location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the same problem. Removed the -arch i386 from the $CFLAGS, as I am only interested in the x64 version. Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, does OS/X not bring a libusb by default. You will need to install one e.g. from MacPorts

Comment: it 10.6 comes with 0.1.13beta which is satisfactory. Either way, i have tried newer versions from mac ports and get the same thing